# Show Django template with a camera stream

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a simple website in Python with Django. I want to load and show a template, and then show, on top of the template's background, the images acquired from the webcam for few seconds. The images do not need to be shown as part of the template, it's ok if they are shown **on top** of it, on a separate window.
The problem is that the template is loaded and showed only **after** the camera code finishes, i.e. I see the window with the camera stream, but only when it finishes the template is loaded. I'd like to have the template loaded and then the window shown. This is the code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def takePicture(request):
    temp = render(request,'pepper/picture.html')
    camstream()
    return temp
```

camstream() is the method that activates the stream from the camera, and it works as expected. It uses pygame, following [this](https://gist.github.com/snim2/255151) tutorial.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Please avoid using `l` as variable name. It can be confused for `1`. In this simple example it doesn't appear severe, but somewehere else it might bite you back. Make up some more meaningfull name instead of just one letter.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically update the page with the pictures acquired? In your question you say that you want to **load** the template and **then** show the webcam images. That means you'll need to use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM after the template has been loaded.

Comment: Your problem is unclear, could you please update your post.

Comment: The post has been modified. Is it clearer? @cezar actually I didn't think of including the images in the template, but just of show the window on the template's background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show content to the user before setting up the camera screen, you need to serve the user HTML before setting up the camera screen. It looks like you're trying to accomplish this by calling

```
temp = render(request,'pepper/picture.html')
```

However, that line just creates HTML from the template provided at pepper/picture.html -- it doesn't actually serve that HTML to the user.

Typically, you would accomplish this by writing the camera logic in javascript and embedding that javascript in `picture.html`. If you'd like to keep everything in django / python, then I guess you could accomplish that by splitting `takePicture` into two views:

```
def picture_without_stream(request):
    return render(request,'pepper/picture.html')

def picture_with_stream(request):
    camstream()
    return render(request,'pepper/picture.html')
```

You could initially load picture_without_stream and when it loads, redirect to picture_with_stream. But that's pretty ugly.